# How to make such small REACT.JS code on PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I make a site on one CMS which is built on php. I don't know **php** myself, since I'm a **front-end** developer. And usually I do websites on js (**React.js**). Considering that the site was written on CMS, the whole site was managed to be done simply by clicking the buttons in the admin panel of the CMS itself.

But I need to make a small php file that displays the **weather** of a specific city **on the page**. Most precisely, three fields and values. I get the values using **API** from `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=32ae008b1c7259324aa50450687fabf5&units=metric`

### The task is to display this on the page:

**City: London

Temparuture: 22.05

Pressure: 1012**

And the API itself (apart from the fields I do not need) looks like this:

```
{"main":{"temp":22.05,"pressure":1012},
"name":"London"}
```

I wrote React.js code that displays the weather:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    city: "",
    temp: "",
    pressure: ""
  }    

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=32ae008b1c7259324aa50450687fabf5&units=metric`);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({
      city: data.name,
      temp: data.main.temp,
      pressure: data.main.pressure
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        City:{this.state.city}
        Temparuture:{this.state.temp}
        Pressure:{this.state.pressure}
      </div>
    );
   }
  }
```

Unfortunately, there is very little time to complete the site and I will not be able to study PHP quickly. Perhaps there are developers here who know both PHP and React.js, and will be able to help me with something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily just use `file_get_contents` to get the response and use `json_decode` to turn it into an object.

Please have a go at it yourself in the future, as this is not a community that always drip-feeds an entire answer. I also would not personally recommend using this code in production.

```php
<?php
    $response = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=32ae008b1c7259324aa50450687fabf5&units=metric");
    $weather = json_decode($response);
?>

<div>City: <?php echo $weather->name ?></div>
<div>Temparuture: <?php echo $weather->main->temp ?></div>
<div>Pressure: <?php echo $weather->main->pressure ?></div>
```

Relevant articles:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

If you have php installed locally, you can run the example code by following the below:

1. Create a folder where the `index.php` file will live
2. Copy the below code into the `index.php` file
3. Run the following command in the folder `php -S localhost:8050`
4. Open `http://localhost:8050` in your web browser

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, your react project is simply a `js` file, so on your `weather_page.php`, add the `js` file in the script tag.

Comment: In my case, this is not possible. Because the requirement that it be written on PHP without connecting the JS. Maybe you can help me remake my code to PHP?

Comment: @antongordon25 That doesn't make any sense... Your problem is very unclear. If you can't use JS, you can't use react.

Comment: @Brian Thompson there is simply a task to display three weather values per page. CMS requires that all custom modules be written in PHP. I wrote the code on React.js not because it is required in the task but because maybe it will be easier for someone to help me remake it to PHP. JS in the project should not be at all.